# Get the auto-generated id - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the id of the element that I inserted in the database with `.key`. However, it returns the `user` value instead of the auto-generated id.

How can I get the auto-generated id ?

```
var mainText = document.getElementById("main-text");
var emailText = document.getElementById("emailtxt");
var prenom = document.getElementById("prenomtxt");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
var heading = document.getElementById("heading");



var firebaseHeadingref = firebase.database().ref().child("titre");
firebaseHeadingref.on('value', function(datasnapchot){
  heading.innerText = datasnapchot.val();
})

function submitClick(){
  var firebaseref = firebase.database().ref();
  var messageText = mainText.value;
  var txtmail = emailText.value;
  var prenomtxt = prenom.value;


  if(messageText == "" || txtmail == "" || prenomtxt == ""){
   alert("Tous les champs doivent être remplis");
   return;
  }

 firebaseref.child("user").push().set({name : messageText, prenom:prenomtxt ,email : txtmail});



 var f = firebase.database().ref().child("user").orderByChild("email").equalTo(txtmail);


 // firebaseref.child("user").push({name: messageText, prenom:prenomtxt, email: txtmail}).then(pushed_user => {
 //
 // console.log(pushed_user.key);
 //
 // });

 f.on("value", function(datasnapchot){
  var id = datasnapchot.val();
  console.log(id);

 });

// location.reload();
}
```

There is a console notice:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase J5 SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import the individual SDK components you intend to use. For the CON builds, these are available in the following manner (replace ‹PACKAGE> with the name of a component - 1.8. auth, database, etc):

[https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-‹PACKAGE›.js](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-%E2%80%B9PACKAGE%E2%80%BA.js)

[image: log :]

Comment: Can you help us by adding Firebase RealtimeDatabase Data and Javascript code into the question??

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like a function:

```
var id = datasnapchot.key();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you push an element you can directly retrieve the auto generated ID without having to call a listener.

```
firebaseref.child("user").push({name: messageText, prenom:prenomtxt, email: txtmail}).then(pushed_user => {

console.log(pushed_user.key);

});
```

You can find another example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Comment: it returns the following error : "it returns the following error : datasnapchot.key is not a function.. "

Answer (score 0):

`var newPostKey = firebaseref.child("user").push().set({name : messageText,prenom:prenomtxt ,email : txtmail}).key;`

"newPostKey" will be your key

Comment: It return "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

ref.push().on("value", function(snapshot) { snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
var id = childSnapshot.key();
console.log(childSnapshot);
  });
});
```

You need to loop using `forEach` and then you will be able to retrieve the push key using `key()`

Comment: Thank you but there is a problem. It does not enter in the foreach.

Comment: Why does it not enter

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var id = datasnapchot.key;
```

Use **datasnapchot.key** instead of **datasnapchot.key()**